# PHP JSON. Confusing issue

Tags: php, linux, centos

Ok I am running CentOS, with PHP 5.2. I recently added the JSON extension. When running

```
php -i
```

.. after installing JSON, it says

```
json

json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1
```

But when I run phpinfo it's not showing the JSON extension as being enabled. I have added the extension to the php.ini file so it loads the json.so file.

I am so confused about this. What could the possible causes of this be?

btw. I am running php as an apache module.

Answer (score 3):

Probably your PHP cli is using a different php.ini file, one that loads the json extension, and the Apache module isn't. `php -i` and `phpinfo()` give information about the loaded php.ini files.

For PHP cli, the php.ini location can be specified through the `PHPRC` environment variable or with `php -c <file|dir>`. For the Apache module, you can use the Apache directive `PHPINIDir`.

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.2 the JSON extension is included in the core, you don't need to include any extensions. If it says JSON support is enabled it should work. Have you actually tried it?

As long as php wasn't compiled with --disable-json.

Comment: You'd be surprised on how often distributions remove extensions from the core. Besides, even if it's in the core, it should show up in `phpinfo`. It could also have been compiled with `--enable-json=shared`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it guys. I added an updated repository, and ran
    yum update php
I made the wrong mistake of assuming I was using 5.2 when infact it was 5.1

After the update it worked.

Answer (score -1):

addition :

The solution is:

```
cd /usr/lib/php/modules (or your modules directory where the json.so file is)

strip json.so

apachectl restart
```

source : http://fanaticalwebworker.blogspot.com/2010/10/json-with-apache-centos-44-and-php-516.html